# sort coordinates points of squares of a list in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

i have a grid of 9 x 9 squares. Around is a bigger square. The coordinates of the square corners are stored unsorted in a list in this way:

```
# upper left corner = x1 y1
# lower left corner = x2 y2
# lower right corner = x3 x3
# upper right corner = x4 y4
```

my_list:

```
[[[x1 y1][x2 y2][x3 y3][x4 y4]] # square 1
  [x1 y1][x2 y2][x3 y3][x4 y4]] # square 5
  [x1 y1][x2 y2][x3 y3][x4 y4]] # square 23
  .
  .
  .
  [x1 y1][x2 y2][x3 y3][x4 y4]]] # square 3
```

i know that i can acces the corners with

```
my_list[0][0]
> [x1 y1]
```

for example and the values with:

```
my_list[0][0][0]
> x1 

my_list[0][0][1]
> y1
```

But, i don´t know how to sort the lists that i have a sorted list like this way:

```
[[square1][square2][square3]...[square8][square9]
 [square10][square11][square12]...[square17][square18]
 .
 .
 .
 [square72][square73][square74]...[square80][square81]]
```

square1 should be the square with the lowest x1 and the lowest y1. Is it right, that i only need the first, maybe the upper left corner? Because, the grid squares have the same lenght and width.

Comment: Is this a plain Python list, or is it a Numpy array?

Comment: How to sort if the lowest x1 is not pair with lowest y1?

Comment: Oh sorry, i dont wrote that actually its a normal python list.

Comment: @stamaimer: thats one of my problems, x1 and x2 should be together

Comment: @robinarthur I mean the lowest x is in (1, 1000) and the lowest y is in (1000, 1). which one should place in` my_list[0][0]` after sort?

Comment: @stamaimer ahh yes you are right. my coordinate system starts in the upper left corner, so my lowest x should have the lowest y. But from your point of view the first square  is in (1,1000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flat `my_list` with shape (9, 9, 2) to 1d list with shape(1, 81, 2), sort it, and then reshape it to original shape.

```
flat_list = [item for row in my_list for item in row]
flat_list.sort()

# If you want to reshape the 1d list with shape(1, 81, 2) to 2d list with shape(9, 9, 2)
result = []
temp = []
count = 0

for item in flat_list:
    temp.append(item)
    count += 1
    if count % 9 == 0:
        result.append(temp)
        temp = []
        count = 0

# You also can use numpy to reshape flat_list to (9, 9, 2)
import numpy to np
result = np.array(flat_list).reshape(9, 9, 2)
```